# How to do a vertical wave animation of a ribbon in svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is that I want to create a svg file (Code is mentioned below) like a vertical ribbon(which is already done), now I want to give a wave effect that will start from the top to the bottom and will be in continuous mode. But it isn't working.

```css
@keyframes thread{
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 200; 
        opacity:.5;  
    }
    to{
        stroke-dashoffset: 2;
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.anime{
    stroke-dasharray: 200;
    animation: thread 2s .4s forwards infinite ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<div class="position-absolute">
    <svg height="200" width="200" >   
        <g class="anime">
     <path id="shape-1"  d="M100 0 c-20 20 -20 25 -10 40 s20 30 -2 60   h50 m11.5 -100 c-20 20 -20 25 -10 40 s20 30 -2 60"
                fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></path>
                <path id="shape-2"  d="M100 0 c-25 25 -25 30 -15 40 s25 35 -9 55 h64 m16.5 -105 c-25 25 -25 30 -15 45 s25 35 -4 60"
                fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
            </path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to eleborate on the wave effect you are trying to create

Comment: Yes..... @SuperDJ

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this(correct me if I'm wrong):

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("cups");
var s = Snap(svg);

var ribbon1 = Snap.select('#ribbon1');
var ribbon2 = Snap.select('#ribbon2');

var ribbon1Points = ribbon1.node.getAttribute('d');
var ribbon2Points = ribbon2.node.getAttribute('d');


var toRibbon2 = function(){
  ribbon1.animate({ d: ribbon2Points }, 1000,  toRibbon1);  
}

var toRibbon1 = function(){
  ribbon1.animate({ d: ribbon1Points }, 1000,  toRibbon2); 
}


toRibbon1();
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ribbon2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

svg {
  fill: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="100" height="130" viewBox="0 0 75 47" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path id="ribbon1" class="cls-1" d="M64.5,64.5c0,15-4,19-4,31a17.23,17.23,0,0,0,10,16h28s-11-8-11-17,1-16,1-30-1-25-1-25h-26S64.5,49.5,64.5,64.5Z" transform="translate(-58.85 -39)"/>
   <path id="ribbon2" class="cls-1" d="M61,60c0,15,5.5,23.5,5.5,35.5s-6,16-6,16h28s5-4,5-13S85,76,85,62s2.5-22.5,2.5-22.5h-26S61,45,61,60Z" transform="translate(-58.85 -39)"/>
</svg>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

it probably requires some tweaking in the paths itself to make for a more realistic effect. Here it is specifically applied to your paths:

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("cups");
var s = Snap(svg);

var ribbon1 = Snap.select('#ribbon1');
var ribbon2 = Snap.select('#ribbon2');

var ribbon1Points = ribbon1.node.getAttribute('d');
var ribbon2Points = ribbon2.node.getAttribute('d');


var toRibbon2 = function() {
  ribbon1.animate({
    d: ribbon2Points
  }, 1000, toRibbon1);
}

var toRibbon1 = function() {
  ribbon1.animate({
    d: ribbon1Points
  }, 1000, toRibbon2);
}


toRibbon1();
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ribbon2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

svg {
  fill: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <svg height="200" width="200">   
        <g class="anime">
     <path id="ribbon1"  d="M100 0 c-20 20 -20 25 -10 40 s20 30 -2 60   h50 m11.5 -100 c-20 20 -20 25 -10 40 s20 30 -2 60"
                fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></path>
                <path id="ribbon2"  d="M100 0 c-25 25 -25 30 -15 40 s25 35 -9 55 h64 m16.5 -105 c-25 25 -25 30 -15 45 s25 35 -4 60"
                fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
            </path>
        </g>
    </svg>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's an extensive [guide](https://codeburst.io/svg-morphing-the-easy-way-and-the-hard-way-c117a620b65f) on how to make this (which I based my answer on). It's basically two SVG paths that morph into each other over time.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @Maharkus, but I want animation something like wave effect. Like hoisted flag moves, something like that but in vertical direction. and in the same shape. I want something like this - https://thumbs.gfycat.com/PeskyPepperyHarpseal-size_restricted.gif